# What to do about getting downvotes on one site for meta posts on another?

Tags: support, help-center, abuse

Recently I had a [query regarding the validity of the functioning of the *Academia* Stack Exchange site](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4523/is-stack-exchange-academia-based-on-a-flawed-premise/4527#4527). Since then, I have had three questions downvoted on Stack Overflow.

This seems to be a rather ridiculous state of affairs, given that the whole point of meta is that we are not penalized for our opinions.

Additionally, the moderator team there did nothing but delete comments of mine in order to make my detractors seem correct, and making me out to be biased. Is there a way to dissociate myself from the Academia Stack Exchange community? Is there no recourse for being stalked and downvoted by the existing members?

Comment: If you believe you're harassed around the SE network, please use the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) link at the bottom of every page. SE staff can investigate and has access to all interactions between your account and other users. If there is evidence of misconduct they are the ones that can take appropriate measures. The community here certainly can't except showing sympathy for your case. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)

Comment: Sure, sounds good to me. Hope the support team is as nice.

Comment: The few people from the support team I interacted with were all friendly, helpful and professional.

Comment: @HaoZeke: That SO reputation could well be restored if the automated system determines it's the result of voting fraud, somewhere in the coming 24 hours...

Comment: @Catija: Considering your edit, this question is actually on-topic on SO meta now... Should it be moved back? (Is that even possible?)

Comment: @Cerbrus If it's closed here, it will go back, yes.

Comment: I've edited the post to remove hyperbole and reflect what I can see happened. As rene and Glorfindel have said, feel free to contact us. The mods on SO won't be able to investigate with so few votes involved. HaoZeke, please make an effort to open discussions with actual numbers, not conceptual and (to be honest) deceptive statements. To the kibitzing commenters, I think this is a good time to stop the hypothetical exchange and find another mystery to be solved.

Comment: Is the deception because I had 3 answers down voted? I have not been too active so those three are a significant amount of my current contribution. I may not have too many posts but surely that doesn't mean my statements are deceptive. @Catija

Comment: This definitely seems to be a clear showing of comments being deleted without any sort of condescension or insult involved. Was there a section of the many deleted comments which are considered offensive? It's nice to see that the only way to get around this network is to hope no one takes offense before I have thousands of posts accumulated.

Comment: You stated that it was "across the network". This is untrue. It was only on SO. You haven't received any downvotes other than to this question, on three questions on SO, and two downvotes on your misplaced question on Academia, which can easily be assumed to result from you asking the question in the wrong place.

Comment: I removed the discussion because it was non-productive, not because it was rude. The comments were obsolete because they related to content I'd removed from the question.

Comment: Is that a common practice? Moderating discussions for not being considered productive? What is the number of sites one needs to be followed across to be considered part of the network? I notice the comments where proof my reputation changes were demanded are now gone and my OP has been edited instead.

Comment: It's incredible that senior users can demand answers, then simply delete them once the mods have done their bidding. Is this really the way SE is supposed to function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: Yes @Mari-LouA, now that the post has been edited to be a duplicate. Definitely. Let us have this closed then? My words here are obviously not to be my own.

Comment: @HaoZeke To be clear... you had zero **answers** downvoted. You keep saying that you did; that is incorrect. You seemed displeased with people asking you to prove that some damage had been done to you, and whether you were damaged or not is kinda irrelevant since you're asking what to do. Even if the question were hypothetical, there's no reason to need proof and we can see the votes quite easily if you contact us. Yes, I remove this sort of thing when it's clearly going off into the weeds.

Comment: The deletion of comments before even an hour has passed by is a fairly common event. This might succeed in decluttering the comment section but it also means a calm discussion leading to clarification cannot be have. It also means users' memories of what was actually said can be fuzzy.

Comment: I have had [my questions downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1895378/haozeke?tab=reputation). Old questions, with accepted answers, suspiciously soon after my unpopular Academia SE post. I did not have any issues proving what damage I felt was done. I **am however**, disappointed that my proof was deleted and used to modify my OP and furthermore that I was then told that because I have not been active enough, and therefore my contribution is not enough for any action against me to be considered abuse, I quote I, and anyone reading this should "find another mystery to be solved".

Comment: @HaoZeke Um... "find another mystery to be solved" was not directed at you since that was unclear, I apologise. I've edited my comment in an attempt to clarify that. It was directed at the people who were arguing with you about the validity of your claim. I have never said your claim was invalid, I've said that the information you're providing is inaccurate and that only the staff can address your concerns. The page you linked to is not visible to regular users. If you want to add a screenshot to your post, feel free but there's no need. As I said, you do not need to prove your claim here.

Comment: I have rubbed some people the wrong way and some might be taking out their frustration with me by gleefully downvoting my posts. I don’t let it bother me because it makes them feel better and it doesn’t really hurt me that much. Keep in mind that a downvote takes away much less reputation than an upvote gives. Spend your energy attracting those upvotes, not getting upset over the downvotes. A downvote should make you double check a post to see if you can improve it. Don’t let some stranger on the Internet ruin your day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have been stalked across the Stack Exchange network and have had almost all my posts downvoted.

The [standard way of reporting serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/295232) is casting a custom flag on one of your posts. Since the issue pertains to *multiple* sites, it's unlikely to be resolved by a single ♦ moderator on one of those sites. If I'd encounter a custom moderator flag asking me to investigate such a cross-site situation, I would escalate the matter to the [Community Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/295232). So it's best contacting them directly via the [Contact Us](/contact) form (which site doesn't matter).

> Is there a way to dissociate myself from the Academia Stack Exchange community?

Yes, there is: you can [delete your account there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/295232) while keeping your other accounts in the network. FWIW, that's unlikely to help in this case; the members you describe already found your other accounts.

Comment: But will deleting my account prevent them from hunting down my other posts?

Comment: @HaoZeke No, not if they already know those other accounts. It will prevent future readers from linking your old posts to other accounts, and it will probably reduce the motivation of your current “fans”. But if they are already downvoting you on your other accounts, they know how to get there already. Though if they don’t bookmark it or whatever they may forget.

Comment: @HaoZeke no. It would be counterproductive and make it difficult for us to see that they're targeting your posts.

Comment: Though not directly related I find it odd that there's no way to block a particular account. That would solve such issues, preventing me from seeing their posts and vice versa.

Comment: That's because Stack Exchange is all about the *content*, not the *users*. That makes your situation painful (I have no better word), though I reserve any judgment since I'm obviously not aware of the entire picture.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for the clarification. It is very frustrating, because the larger SE sites are never so petty, I guess it is only to be expected from certain smaller SE sites though.